# How do I use the Glide wrapper on Diablo 2 with PlayOnLInux?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Hi I just installed Diablo 2 via PlayOnLinux in my Netbook and now I would like to know how to make the Glide Wrapper work. I also install 1.14d patch so I can play on BattleNet, but this patch disabled the option for the game to automatically select the Glide wrapper. I know that in Windows there's is a runaround for this which is to add the parameter -3dfx in the properties of the D2 shortcut. Thing is I don't know how to do this in PlayOnLinux nor do I know if it's the correct way. So please can somebody tell me what to do?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu ? I would ask on the PlayOnLinux forums. https://www.playonlinux.com/en/forums.html

Comment: Sorry but there's a "game" tag as well. I tought it appropriate.

Comment: I see the confusion. I suppose it depends on if you are installing or configuring Ubuntu or, as in your case, you are configuring a game with playonlinux. Just trying to suggest you are going to have better luck on the playonlinux forums .